# My Count Down Timer is not properly working for Listview in android

Tags: java, android

When am set Count down timer for single progress circle its work perfectly but when am using it for Listview my Progress Circle not work perfectly. Please tell me How to implement count down timer for listview in android.

```
private ListView lvHomeItems;
private List<HomeContent> homeListContent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    lvHomeItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_home_activity);
    homeListContent = new ArrayList<>();
    homeListContent.add(new HomeContent("3","22-10-2016","BDOI501",System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000));
    homeListContent.add(new HomeContent("2","21-10-2016","BDOI502",System.currentTimeMillis() + 22000));
    homeListContent.add(new HomeContent("4","20-10-2016","BDOI503",System.currentTimeMillis() + 34000));
    homeListContent.add(new HomeContent("1","19-10-2016","BDOI504",System.currentTimeMillis() + 46000));


    lvHomeItems.setAdapter(new CountdownAdapter(HomeActivity.this, homeListContent));
}
private class HomeContent {
    long expirationTime;
    String Date;
    String Id;
    String PrescriptionNo;


    public HomeContent(String PrescriptionNo,String Date,String Id,long expirationTime) {
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
        this.PrescriptionNo = PrescriptionNo;
        this.Date = Date;
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
public class CountdownAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomeContent> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<ViewHolder> homeListContent;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (homeListContent) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (ViewHolder holder : homeListContent) {

                        holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public CountdownAdapter(Context context, List<HomeContent> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        homeListContent = new ArrayList<>();
        startUpdateTimer();
    }

    private void startUpdateTimer() {
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_content, parent, false);
            holder.tvCountDownTimer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_home_countTimeDown);
            holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_home_date);
            holder.tvOrderId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_home_order_id);
            holder.tvPrescriptionNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_priscription_no);
            holder.tvViewDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view);
            holder.btnSelectBid = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_bid);
            holder.mRingProgressBar = (RingProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_1);


            //doSomeThing();

            holder.tvViewDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PrescriptionListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            holder.btnSelectBid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // bidVenderList();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SelectBidActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            synchronized (homeListContent) {
                homeListContent.add(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.setData(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvViewDetails, tvCountDownTimer, tvDate, tvOrderId, tvPrescriptionNo;
    Button btnSelectBid;
    HomeContent mProduct;
    RingProgressBar mRingProgressBar;

    public void setData(HomeContent item) {
        mProduct = item;
        tvOrderId.setText("Order Id : " + item.Id);
        tvDate.setText("Date : " + item.Date);
        tvPrescriptionNo.setText("No of Prescription :  " + item.PrescriptionNo);
        updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
        final long timeDiff = mProduct.expirationTime - currentTime;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                        mProgressStatus += 1;
                        // Update the progress bar
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                mRingProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                                mRingProgressBar.setMax(60);
                                if (timeDiff > 0) {
                                    final int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                                    final int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                                    tvCountDownTimer.setText(minutes + " : " + seconds);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

    }
}
```

When am start my activity it not work perfectly... please tell me solution